# location of specific function in Junit source

Tags: java, junit

JUnit 4.x does not provide for private methods to have test methods generated for them.  I was looking in the junit source code (downloaded from github) for where this is enforced in the code but I was not able to locate it. I did find where it checks that test methods themselves are public, but I am looking for where it either explicitly checks a target class's methods' modifiers or otherwise omits or skips processing private methods of the target class. Does anyone know where this code might be located?

ADDENDUM:

OK so, we've been having a nice little chat on this and here's what's been learned. Suppose you have a class foo with two methods, bar and baz, which are both private. Ordinarily using a combination of some IDE and JUnit4.x you cannot make JUnit to generate test stubs for these methods on account of their being private. This rule "do not generate test stubs for private methods" is enforced at the level of the IDE and is not a part of JUnit per se.

So with a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private void bar(){} 
    private void baz(){}
}
```

you can't get this generated:

```
public class FooTest{

    @Test
    public void testBar(){}

    @Test
    public void testBaz(){}
}
```

But if you alter your IDE, leaving JUnit alone completely you can get those test methods generated. Note that JUnit WILL check in its Runner if the methods marked with @Test are public and refuse to run them if they're not, but that's a different concern.

Comment: Which runner are you using?

Comment: Well the default would do by way of example I suppose. Let's say BlockJUnitForClassRunner as that seems to be a major one ..I am not very familiar with JUnit

Answer (score 3):

The actual check is in `FrameworkMethod#validatePublicVoid(boolean, List<Throwable>)`.

`Runner` implementations that extend from `ParentRunner` make a call to `validate()` in the `ParentRunner` constructor. That `validate()` is `private` but it delegates to a `protected` method which implementations override called `collectInitializationErrors(List<Throwable>)`. `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`'s implementation calls `validateInstanceMethods(errors);` (which is deprecated, so it's weird) that ends up calling the method above.

---

Confused edit:

I don't know what you're asking anymore. There's nothing special about JUnit. It's just a library. You write Java code that has a number of annotations that make sense to JUnit. **JUnit cannot prevent you from writing code.**

JUnit or you (or your IDE) provide a class that has a `main` method.

It gets executed like so

```
java -cp <some class path> TheClassWithMain <more arguments>
```

just like any other `java` program.

The JUnit classes, ie. `ParentRunner`, its children, and others related, use reflection to scan your provided test classes. They do this to build up a test suite, ie. setup methods, test methods, tear down methods, thrown exception expectations, assertion expectations, etc.

The JUnit API has very specific documentation about what is allowed and what isn't. You can find the javadoc [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/). For `@Test` for example, it says

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the `public void` method to which
>   it is attached can be run as a test case.

This is true regardless of your IDE.

**Remember, these are not compile time checks, they are run time checks that are the result of reflective analysis of the code.**

Now, your IDE, whatever it is, might have a JUnit plugin that does these checks statically, ie. doing static analysis of your code, not run time analysis. It can do this because the source code is available.

If your question is about IDE behavior, you'll need to specify the IDE you're using. If your question is about how does JUnit prevent `private` `@Test` methods from being run, the answer is above.

Comment: @user3277785 Just to explain what I did. I download the sources of JUnit and ran my unit tests in debug mode. I looked up the stack trace for where the `@Test` method was invoked. I then checked where it was retrieved and how the runner used it.

Comment: Super thanks for elucidating your problem solving method.. most valuable answer one can get.

Comment: Darn..I approved this answer while I was away from my IDE; now I have to "unapprove" it (is that a thing?) . Anyway the important point is that the FrameowrkMethod method you cite is what I was talking about when I said I fond where JUnit checks where test methods themselves are public. That's what that method is doing. But before it checks it's own test method is correct , it has to create that test method from the target class. During that process, when it finds a target class method which is not public, it has to explicitly refrain from creating a test method for it . THAT's the part I want

Comment: @user3277785 **All** methods that have an annotation are added when the `ParentRunner` creates the target `TestClass` (check out its constructor). These methods end up in the `fMethodsForAnnotations` field. This is a `Map<Class, List<FrameworkMethod>>`, where the keys are annotation types. The `Block4JUnitClassRunner` retrieves only the `List<FrameworkMethod>` for the `@Test` annotation and runs those after validating them.

Comment: All true, as I also discovered when perusing the source. Unfortunately none of that answers the question and there's a reason for that. I think the answer to my question is "JUnit doesn't make those checks". I seems that JUnit doesn't actually create any test classes, it just runs them (and checks to be sure they're legal, as we discovered). It seems to be that the IDE or "other" is responsible for identifying qualifying candidates in a class for unit testing then creating the stubs (at least in IntelliJ. Mystery solved.  Of course the programmer is responsible for implementing those tests!

Comment: Many thanks Sotirios for your attention and time. I am not sure how Stackoverflow actually works.. are there points to be awarded that I can give you or something like this?

Comment: @user3277785 You asked for `I am looking for where it either explicitly checks a target class's methods' modifiers or otherwise omits or skips processing private methods of the target class.` That's done where you found it in the `validatePublicVoid(..)`. JUnit creates a `TestClass` object that wraps your class that contains `@Test` (and other annotations) annotated methods. The IDE doesn't do any such thing. All the IDE typically does is recognize that a method has a `@Test` method and decides to execute it with JUnit rather than running its `main` method.

Comment: @user3277785 The candidates are built based on their annotations. JUnit considers a number of them: `@Before`, `@Test`, `@After`, etc. Each of these has its own life cycle in a test run.

Comment: Sotirios, Hey I am back. I don't have enough reputation points to start a chat thread. I am sure I am right for the following reason(s). First and foremost, without changing anything in the JUnit libraries, I was able to both generate tests and run them for private methods of a target class. If Junit forbade this, I could not have suceeded without altering JUnit's libraries. Second the specific way I achieved this strongly and clearly indicates that it's the IDE preventing private methods from having tests generated- not only was the code located in my IDE, but it was easy to fix.

Comment: Finally, the code we were both looking at in JUnit is responsible for checking that the test method about to be run by JUnit's runner (not the target's method which is being tested by that test method) is public. But that is not what my original question was- my original question was how to generate unit tests for private methods of a target class.

Comment: @user3277785 `I was able to both generate tests and run them for private methods of a target class.` Can you give an example? You can add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: @user3277785 I've added an edit to my answer. It was too long to fit in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods in a class are not visible outside the class, so they are not visible to a JUnit test class.  That is how the Java language works and JUnit does not have to have any code to check that.

If you want the private methods to be visible for testing, but not for other purposes, one common solution is instead to make them default scope - sometimes called "package private" - by omitting the scope from the declaration:

```
void function() {...
```

instead of

```
private void function() {...
```

If you do that, JUnit test classes in the same package will have access to them for testing.

Comment: JUnit uses reflection to invoke your `@Test` annotated methods. Through reflection, you can access and invoke private methods.

Comment: User258.. I don't think that this is the mechanism since test classes can be defined as inner classes of the class to be tested, in which case the test generating mechanism would have visibility.. also, iteration of the target class's methods via reflection, which I think is what JUnit does, would cause the test generating code to encounter private methods of the target class during the course of test method generation...

Comment: Sotirios-thanks for the tip,but it's not actually my question ...:-)

Comment: @user3277785 What tip? I'm just saying what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My interpretation of the question was that he was asking about private methods in the class under test, not private JUnit test methods, and based on his comments I still think that's true.